# A sudokey and 14 messages

Tags: cipher, sudoku, mazes, three-dimensional

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #15: Multi Puzzle — two (or more) puzzles in one](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7514/monthly-topic-challenge-15-multi-puzzle-two-or-more-puzzles-in-one).</sub>
[image]
Remarks:
Feel free to post partial solutions.
This is a multi-puzzle: If you found the titular 14 messages, you are done. There is no final step to combine the messages.
Though difficulty is hard to predict, I expect the east and west puzzle to
be easiest. Some of the messages are hints, so if you want maximum challenge, try to ignore them.

First hints:

> east-west yields the shortest paths.
>  east-west has part of the solution.
>  east-west yields the solution.
>  east-west has nothing to do with the solution.

> The path from east to west starts small
>  Dawn is not a time

More hints

> The layout: The center should be recognizable as (probably) a sudoku, while the other grids seem mangled somehow.
>  This suggest that a sudoku should be solved first and used to solve (part of) the other grids.
>  The title (also) suggests the sudoku is 'the key'.
>  If the sudoku is solved, consider the properties of a sudoku; and how they can be used to alter letters in a 9x9 grid, there are several; test them on the grids.

> Check the labels:

> Cipher: Which one of the grids has a lot of less used letters; and how could the sudoku be used to encode those letters?

> Three dimensional: How could a sudoku display something 3 dimensional? Does this remind you of a game? How can you then see a hidden message?

> Mazes: How could a sudoku display a maze? (mazes do not necessarily have walls; mazes are just twisting paths with an occasional choice of direction)

Extra hints:

> Starting from the lower-case letter, find 2 words while going to the other side of the grid. How do the directions relate to the center sudoku?

> The reference to city is because of some similarity with the skyscrapers game.

> You might have noticed SUDOKU in the bottom grid, look at the corresponding numbers in the sudoku; Realizing how do they match the form of the word may help find more words.

Stonger hints for the bottom puzzle

> To find the messages you need to construct an arrow maze

> Transform sudoku numbers to arrows (numpad style)

> find routes through that maze

> map the bottom grid upon that maze to read along those routes

Comment: Hi, could you check if the 4th line in the right puzzle is correct?

Comment: You are right. Corrected - not to self: I should really use a program to encode , the next time I try something this big..

Comment: I see SUDOKU on a line at the top right of the south puzzle... is it relevant?

Comment: @NumberBasher It is not there by accident.

Comment: still not sure how i can comprehend the numpad compass (especially how i can utilize it) though...

Comment: @NumberBasher I added a hint; not sure if you want one and if it is still too vague, but I find it hard to estimate what would spoil the puzzle.

Comment: @Retudin I still just can't do it; maybe put a rot13 clue in the comments?

Comment: I'd like a hint as well @Retudin

Comment: See how many of the 4 new ones you need to get further... ps: should I also add more hints for the top grid (now)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Parts 1-3 were first solved by [Alaiko](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122687)*

Part 1

> The solution to the sudoku in the middle is
>  [image]

Part 2

> Next we should look at the eastern grid. If we read the letters on each row in the order given by the sudoku numbers (so 7 in the beginning of first row means we start by taking the seventh letter of the first row), we get this
>  [image]
>
>  From here, we can read the first three messages
>
>  **1. THE SUDOKU IS THE MAP OF THE SOUTHERN JUNGLE**
>  **2. LOOK AT THE CITY AT DUSK AND DAWN**
>  **3. ADD OFFSETS TO LETTERS**

Part 3

> We can use message 3 as a hint for the western grid. Offsetting the letters by the sudoku values gives
>  [image]
>
>  This gives us two more messages
>
>  **4. THE HIDDEN PART OF THE CITY CONTAINS AN ODD MESSAGE AND EVEN A RED HERRING**
>  **5. THE NUMPAD IS OUR COMPASS**

Part 4

> Next we can look at the southern grid and use messages 1 and 5 as hints. "Numpad is our compass" means that we should replace the numbers of the sudoku in the corresponding directions on a numpad.
>  [image]
>
>  This gives the following map for the sudoku
>  [image]
>
>  If we treat the 5=? as a wild card, the shortest paths from each of the borders to the opposite sides are these
>  [image]
>
>  Overlaying them with the southern grid gives
>  [image]
>
>  This gives four more messages
>
>  **6. NICE SUDOKU**
>  **7. USE SUDOKU AS THE HEIGHT MAP**
>  **8. A USELESS 1**
>  **9. THIS IS USELESS**
>
>  Furthermore, we should also check the unused cells
>  [image]
>
>  These give one more message
>
>  **10. YOU EXPLORED THE UNCHARTED JUNGLE WELL DONE!**

Part 5

> Messages 2, 4 and 7 give hints for the northern grid. Message 7 tells us to treat the sudoku as a height map. So treating the numbers as heights, we can check which cells are visible from the west
>  [image]
>
>  Overlaying with the north grid gives
>  [image]
>
>  and reading from right to left gives the message
>
>  **11. AT 5 TRY ANY OF 8 ELSE EG PATH 6 EAST**
>
>  Doing the same thing looking from east gives
>  [image]
>
>  and
>  [image]
>
>  This time reading from bottom to top gives the message
>
>  **12. TAKE 4 TIMES THE SHORTEST PATH**
>
>  The "hidden" cells in the sudoku can be divided into even and odd numbers like this
>  [image]
>  (The blue cell is different colour because the corresponding letter actually belongs with the odd numbers.)
>
>  Overlaying again with the northern grid gives
>  [image]
>
>  Now, we can read the final two messages
>  **13. SOME RED HERRING**
>  **14. EAST TO WEST N 2 S AND IN REVE(r)SE**
>
>  And messages 11, 12 and 14 clearly give hints for solving the southern puzzle which we did in part 4!

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Partial answer:</sup>

So my starting point was noticing

> the last row on the east puzzle. 
>  The letters on that side can be anagrammed to "TOLETTERS". Furthermore, I realised that the numbers in the Sudoku for that row seem to be indicating where each letter in the East block should finally end up at. (For example, the 1 in Row 9 of the Sudoku appears in column 3. So this indicates that the L, which appears in column 1 for the east puzzle should end up at column 3.). 
>  Hence, it seems if we solve the Sudoku, we will be able to re-arrange the letters in the East block. 
>  Since I already knew the final arrangement of the letters in the last row of the east block, I can fill up the last row of the Sudoku first. By process of elimination using Sudoku logic, I got here. 
>  [image: Sudoku_1]

This allows us to make some good progress on the Sudoku.

> The majority of the last 3 rows can be then filled in as shown below. 
>  [image: Sudoku_2]
>  From here, just using basic Sudoku-solving techniques will solve the Sudoku fairly quickly. 
>  [image: Sudoku_3]

Following that,

> we can now proceed to decipher what the right side reads. Rearranging the letters for each row as indicated by the numbers for that row, we get 
>  `T H E S U D O K U` 
>  `I S T H E M A P O` 
>  `F T H E S O U T H` 
>  `E R N J U N G L E` 
>  `L O O K A T T H E` 
>  `C I T Y A T D U S` 
>  `K A N D D A W N A` 
>  `D D O F F S E T S` 
>  `T O L E T T E R S` 
>  Essentially, what we have here are three statements.
>  **1. THE SUDOKU IS THE MAP OF THE SOUTHERN JUNGLE**. 
>  This probably is a clue to solve the south puzzle, but I currently have no idea what to make of this, so let's move on.
>  **2. LOOK AT THE CITY AT DUSK AND DAWN** 
>  I don't know what to do with this as well for now, so let's look at the last one.
>  **3. ADD OFFSETS TO LETTERS**
>  Ah, this seems promising. The puzzle on the west side is filled entirely with letters, so perhaps this is referring to adding the **numbers in the Sudoku** to the **letters on the West side puzzle**. Let's try that out.

Trying out that last step will give us the following for the West side puzzle:

> `T H E H I D D E N` 
>  `P A R T O F T H E` 
>  `C I T Y C O N T A` 
>  `I N S A N O D D M` 
>  `E S S A G E A N D` 
>  `E V E N A R E D H` 
>  `E R R I N G T H E` 
>  `N U M P A D I S O` 
>  `U R C O M P A S S` 
>  There are two statements this time round.
>  **1. THE HIDDEN PART OF THE CITY CONTAINS AN ODD MESSAGE AND EVEN A RED HERRING**
>  **2. THE NUMPAD IS OUR COMPASS**. 
>  However, this is where I am currently stuck. I realise that there are arrows on the 2, 4, 6 and 8 keys on the Numpad and indeed, those very numbers appear once in the North puzzle. But I am not sure where to go from there. If I go through the grid in the direction each number is pointing, I don't get any readable words. Perhaps the "compass" needs to be interpreted in a different way?
>  Besides that, I still haven't figured out what to do with the other clues I have found. 
>  However, I do note that the puzzle is tagged with [maze](/questions/tagged/maze) and [three-dimensional](/questions/tagged/three-dimensional), which I haven't seem to make use of yet...

Comment: Hm, Well done so far. It seems I made a few mistakes, so I will correct one of yours: past should be part.

Comment: Maybe numpad also includes 1379 for the diagonals? not sure about 5 though